# NSXMLParser fails to parse certain text strings

Tags: ios, xcode, nsxmlparser

I am finding that the following XML strings are not parsed by NSXMLParser (XCode/iOS) due to prohibited characters. How should XML string be escaped before being sent to XML parser, if escaping is necessary.

```
@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
 <Elem xmlns=\"Sample\"><Text Text=\"some text <name@somcompany.com> \"></Text></Elem>";

@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
 <Elem xmlns=\"Sample\"><Text Text=\"some text \"quoted text\" \"></Text></Elem>";
```

Both generate the following error:

```
Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=38 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
(NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 38.)
```

This works without error:

```
@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<Elem xmlns=\"Sample\"><Text Text=\"some text \'quoted text\' \"></Text></Elem>";
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try escaping the characters with percent encoding.

```
str = @" \">";
str = [str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Then you can recover them with

```
str = [str stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

But I am not sure if you are creating the XML correctly or if you are creating it in the first place.

#### Edit

The source (whoever generates that XML) is incorrect and must escape the text. You cannot do this with the parser.

Comment: I am not creating the XML. It comes from another source. BTW, the above fix gave a different error: Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 4.)